# "alloc init" on WKInterfaceController subclass from XCTestCase crashes

Tags: ios, unit-testing, watchkit

I'm trying to write unit tests for my WatchKit code.  I followed the instructions in this [article](http://www.raywenderlich.com/94672/watchkit-faq) under Debugging and Unit Testing for setting up tests for my WatchKit code.

The only thing, is that, while I'm writing an XCTestCase subclass to unit test one of my WKInterfaceControllers, when the line is executed where I alloc/init it, EXEC_BAD_ACCESS crash.

```
- (void)testAwakeWithContext
{
    //CRASH on this line
    WKInterfaceController *interfaceController = [[WKInterfaceController alloc] init];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can Confirm that this happens on WatchKit 2.0 as well (in case you thought patience was the answer) BUT in theory you can move the logic into an NSObject or similar and test it independently of the InterfaceController, whilst still being able to call the logic? Same obviously goes for the data etc.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't create new WatchKit objects programmatically. The must all be set from a Storyboard file. I don't think there is an official way to test WatchKit code at the moment.

I found this article with an interesting project that you could use to test your code. Check it out: http://pivotallabs.com/watchkit-test-tools-pivotalcorekit/

Comment: Not totally true, you can phyiscally alloc/init WKInterfaceControllers within the context of a watchkit app runtime.  I agree that you SHOULDNT do this, and I'm just pointing out that the behavior is different than I'm seeing, from the test- it crashes.  That is a good PivotalLabs article too.

Comment: Hello, I read the article but it seems that Cedar only works with objective-c? The app I want to test is all written in swift. Did you guys get anywhere in this watchkit-unit-testing problem ?